# Spring Cloud Eureka client doesn't start due to jersey

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I couldn't start eureka client because from what i understood, it uses Jersey and so does spring boot. So i excluded jersey from spring cloud eureka client as follow down below, but i'm still have the same error
**pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.primo.business</groupId>
    <artifactId>profile</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>profile</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**stacktrace :**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:381) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:184) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:127) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:490) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35d361f.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.primo.business.profile.ProfileApplication.main(ProfileApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:436) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:283) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:279) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:290) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/client/apache4/config/DefaultApacheHttpClient4Config
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder.build(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:183) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.buildLegacy(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:230) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.build(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:204) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.create(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:161) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.Jersey1TransportClientFactories.newTransportClientFactory(Jersey1TransportClientFactories.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.scheduleServerEndpointTask(DiscoveryClient.java:528) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:423) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.config.DefaultApacheHttpClient4Config
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 73 common frames omitted

2021-01-12 17:56:22.799  WARN 49329 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-01-12 17:56:22.802  INFO 49329 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-12 17:56:22.809  INFO 49329 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-12 17:56:22.813  INFO 49329 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-01-12 17:56:22.816  INFO 49329 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-01-12 17:56:22.820  INFO 49329 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-01-12 17:56:22.836  INFO 49329 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-12 17:56:22.853 ERROR 49329 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.primo.business.profile.ProfileApplication.main(ProfileApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

i deleted my IntelliJ cache, i removed the artifact from .m2 before doing a clean install. Maybe that i forgot something ?

Comment: I'll look at it here in a bit and let you know

Comment: Okay, thank you @spencergibb !

Comment: Can I ask why you have `spring-boot-starter-jersey` and `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server` as a dependency?

Comment: So removing eureka-server and the jersey starter fixes things for me. Can you answer my question above?

Comment: @spencergibb, i can say nothing else than thanks!! It works like a charm, but i'm afraid that it will cause issues if i'll have to work with jersey (i removed spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server and spring-boot-starter-jersey that were unnecessary)

Comment: then add the things in `exclusions` above and jersey will work.